# Type warning Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pep

Given  the following example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x: (float, np.ndarray) = 0.05):
        self.x = x
```

what i intend with it is to give a hint to the user that the argument x can be a float or a numpy array. If nothing is given, set default to 0.05. Is this the right use ? If yes, why does Pycharm warm when i initiate A as follows ? :

```
 a = A(x=np.random.rand(3, 3))   #Expected type 'float', got 'ndarray' instead
```

If its not the right use, where is my thinking wrong? Doesnt x:(float,np.ndarray) mean that x can be a float or np.ndarray?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Union`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#union-types):

```
from typing import Union

class A:
    def __init__(self, x: Union[float, np.ndarray] = 0.05):
        self.x = x
```

Comment: So what does x:(float,np.ndarray) mean ?

Comment: @JustANoob simply `float`. Not sure why though